# How to edit URL Slug?

Tags: urls, slug

Some of my blog post slugs show abnormal characters within the edit post screen (ie. 3%e2%80%8b-%e2%80%8bperks%e2%80%8b-%e2%80%8bof%e2%80%8b-%e2%80%8bsmartphone-based%e2%80%8b-%e2%80%8belds) but shows a clean slug on the actual web browser.

These long messy slugs are showing up on my SEO audit as URL errors. Does anyone know how to fix these slugs?

Comment: It sounds like you're using special characters in your URLs. For example, `%80` translates to a backtick, which is a special character so it has to be html encoded. If you limit your URLs to alphanumeric, hyphens, and underscores, you shouldn't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the slug for most content types. Check your sidebar when you have it open for editing - it should look something like this:

[image]

Moreover, some SEO plugins (like Yoast) also allow you to specify a slug. If you change the slug (and thus the URL to pages) you might want to use some sort of redirect plugin that can catch changes and redirect incoming traffic on the old URL.